# How to override the connectionstring value of AzureWebJobsStorage to a new value in .net core function app

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have to specify the storage account connections attribute based on some condition

eg:

```
if(condition=true)
[StorageAccount("ConnectionString1")]
else
[StorageAccount("ConnectionString2")]
```

Do we have some conditional attributes to achieve this in .net?

Comment: what do you mean by conditional attribute?

Comment: I need to specify one of the storageAccount connection as an attribute. I am just checking whether .net has that feature

Comment: you can put them in the Function App Configuration -> Application settings and load them at runtime. string ConnectionString1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

Comment: I am new to this can you just explain in detail  may be with an eg:

Comment: if (condion is true)
               connectionString = "abc";
            else
              connectionString = "def";      
        [StorageAccount("ConnectionString")] 
             public async Task Run()
        {}

Answer (score 0):

**One of the workarounds I did to override the Azure Function App Storage Accounts is**:

1. Created a .NET Core 6 Azure Function App and one extra storage account in which both storage account connection strings are noted in My Function App `local.settings.json` file like below:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "Get_Conn_String_from_AzureStorageAcc_AccessKeys",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureStorageAccount02": "<Get_Conn_String_from_AzureStorageAcc_AccessKeys>"
  }
}
```

2. To override the different storage account based on condition from the Azure Function, I have written the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace KrishNet6CoreFunctionApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            if (name == "HariKrishna")
            {
                var constring1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
                log.LogInformation("Function Execution logs will be stored in 1st storage account.");
            }
            else
            {
                var constring1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureStorageAccount02");
                log.LogInformation("Function Execution logs will be stored in 2nd storage account.");
            }


                string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                    ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                    : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Result**:

[image: IfCondTrueUse1stStorageAcc]

If the parameter name value is different, then utilize the 2nd Storage account to store logs, perform any other operations/activities:

[image: IfCondfalseUse2ndStorageAcc]